# Magento quantity update in cart popup

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to update qty of cart items on click of + and - buttons . how to do this within magento , and outside magento, as I have implemented the same pop-up in wordpress , where I pull the cart items from magento. Here is the example of what I am trying to achieve. https://www.hitmeister.de/ (Cart Pop-up)

Answer (score 0):

For this feature you need to add the javascript in the `cart.phtml` which is located in yout themes `checkout/cart.phtml` template directory

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".product-cart-actions").prepend('<input type="button" value="-" id="minus1" class="minus" />');
jQuery(".product-cart-actions .qty").after('<input type="button" value="+" id="add1" class="plus" />');

jQuery(".plus").click(function(){
var currentVal = parseInt(jQuery(this).prev('.qty').val());
if (!currentVal || currentVal=="" || currentVal == "NaN") currentVal = 0;
jQuery(this).prev(".qty").val(currentVal + 1);
jQuery(this).siblings('.btn-update').css('display','block');
});
jQuery(".minus").click(function()
{
var currentVal = parseInt(jQuery(this).next(".qty").val());
if (currentVal == "NaN") currentVal = 0;
if (currentVal > 0)
{
jQuery(this).next(".qty").val(currentVal - 1);
}
jQuery('.btn-update').css('display','block');
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i already implemented this java script and it is working fine. The question is to update the cart dynamically in the pop-up as shown in the example website.